# How to create custom drag and drop web components for a web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do some R&D work around for my web app.

[image]

In the preceding image I have described my requirement. let say I have some custom web components like components 1, components 2 etc in the left side. Users should be able to drag and drop components into the play area and should be generate predefined some xml or text snippet belong to that component and that generated value should be store in the variable for later use. Currently I am using Angular and JS and HTML languages to achieve my requirement. I know I can use HTML5 drag and drop feature for items. But how can I generate some code snippet or text belong to that dragged items?

Comment: check [this](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/)